# How do get a Grid column to Auto size to content but not clip the content if it gets too large?

Tags: user-interface, silverlight-2.0

I have a DataGrid embedded inside the first column of a Grid. I want the grid column to auto size to content, but when I do this and the DataGrid gets too wide (when columns are added by the user) the DataGrid is clipped by the containing column. Essentially I need to retain the scrolling behaviour of the DataGrid, but have the DataGrid shrink to content and never be clipped.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data">
<Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border><!--Toolbar content goes here--></Border>
        <data:DataGrid
            MaxHeight="350"
            Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="80" MaxWidth="200"/>
```

Comment: I don't want to set a maximum width as I would like the grid to get as wide as it's container (when the browser window is resized).